# Loopback 4 and Mongodb : All model's id are null on response

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, v4l2loopback

It is the first time that I use this version (4) for development and I have a problem with loopback and mongodb indexing.

Of the two ids that are inside the db loopback it does not collect any.

It's a problem of the API or DB?

---

**Model [Loopback]**

```
import { Entity, model, property } from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class Ad extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    required: true,
  })
  id: number;
 <...>
  constructor(data?: Partial<Ad>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

**Data on Mongo:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c0e9c7730146d2448746834"
    },
    "id": 110722,
    "creation_date": 1492075600000,
    "update_date": 1492075921000,
    ...
}
```

**Response on loopback GET */ads***

```
[{
    "id": null,
    "creation_date": 1492075600000,
    "update_date": 1492075921000,
    ...
  },...]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Hello from the LoopBack team :)*

I don't see any obvious problem in the code snippets you posted. What happens when you change id's type from `number` to `string`? Will it fix the problem?

Most likely, you have found a bug in LoopBack 4. Please report it via GitHub: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues

Comment: When I change the type to string appears the mongo id '5c0e9c7730146d2448746834'. How can I get the number id 110722 as the current id in the loopback response?

Comment: IDK, to be honest. Please open a GitHub issue and we can follow-up from there.

Comment: I solved the issue renaming the no-mongo id and using the mongo index as current id. No problem.
I don't know if I have to open a new question but I have a doubt, what is the best way to integrate a json web token auth on loobpack 4?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by changing the id=String. Mongodb id contains both string and number. So, if you change the type of id=string (Model) the issue will be fixed.